# Insufficient Sitemap

Tags: sitemap, concrete5

I am using concrete5 as CMS for my website. I have received a message from google search console stating" When we tested a sample of the URLs from your Sitemap, we found that the site's robots.txt file was blocking access to some of the URLs. If you don't intend to block some of the URLs contained in the Sitemap, please use our robots.txt analysis tool to verify that the URLs you submitted in your Sitemap are accessible by Googlebot. All accessible URLs will still be submitted."
when I investigate my sitemap, my website domain/sitemap.xml I found that it all contains admin links not the URL of the website pages for the user.
I generate a new sitemap from automated jobs and clear the cache but still the problem exist.
I'm using cdn to generate urls, is there anything I could do to fix that issue?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is really strange.
First Concrete5 doesn't generate a robots.txt file. It does however add a robot meta tag with noindex to pages using the relevant attribute.
The default installation also comes with a robots.txt file that disallows specific folders inside the "applications" folder so nothing to do with pages.

Last, the sitemap generating job excludes all system pages and all dashboard pages from the sitemap.

Could you share some lines from your sitemap that point to admin pages to see what's going on?

Comment: That is the exactly the same message that came to me through google search console. for what appears on the sitemap, all the urls start with admin.domainname.com/en/page path